# How to add two buttons in eclipse one for playing an mp3 file and the other for stopping it

Tags: java, android, media-player

I am a newbie in android app development. For now my challenge is to add two buttons in my UI one for playing an mp3 file and the other for stopping it. I am able to do the first successfully and as I try to do the stop one, I see no result. My code is as following:

```
package ir.polyglotcenter.childrenmostfrequentwords;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Main extends Activity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button myButtonOne = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_audio);
    myButtonOne.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MediaPlayer media = MediaPlayer.create(Main.this, R.raw.audio);
            media.start();

        }
    });
    //this is to stop the audio flow
    Button myButtonTwo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_stop);
    myButtonTwo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MediaPlayer media = MediaPlayer.create(Main.this, R.raw.audio);
            media.stop();

        }
    });

}
}
```

Comment: Im also a noob, but I think you are initializing the media object again in Stop click listener. You need to create mediaPlayer object before the listeners and just use media.Play() and media.stop() in respective click listeners. Do not initialize mediaPlayer in either of listeners. (I could be wrong but worth a try)

Comment: create the `MediaPlayer` outside the listener then use `isPlaying` method to check MediaPlayer instance is playing

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
public class Main extends Activity {

    protected MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(Main.this, R.raw.audio);

        Button myButtonOne = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_audio);
        myButtonOne.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                mMediaPlayer.prepare();
                mMediaPlayer.start();
            }
        });
        //this is to stop the audio flow
        Button myButtonTwo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_stop);
        myButtonTwo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(mMediaPlayer.isPlaying())
                    mMediaPlayer.stop();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: yup that's what I was talking about, keeping mediaPlayer object the same +1

Comment: Thanks alot it worked out but still there is tiny problem. When I want to stop the audio and replay it by clicking the start btn, nothing happens. it seems that the code is working only for one round of instructions. What shall i do?

Answer (score 1):

Play and Stop all song for all rows.

The Point is implement MediaPlayer in the loop of if or any loop you have:

```
if(playandstop==true){
mp=MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, resourceIIIDD);
mp.start();
playandstop=false;
}else{
    mp.stop();
    playandstop=true;
}
```